# How to customize history command output?

Tags: bash, security, daemon, history

I want to append user info in command history  i.e  who has executed a particular command?

Currently in linux we just get the command name executed and not other info.

I tried to find the process which updates bash_history file,but couldn't find.
So, please help me finding the process/daemon writing in bash_history file, so that, i can add user info also.

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@mmweb ~]# echo $HISTFILE
/root/.bash_history
[root@mmweb ~]# su -l wspace
wspace@mmweb:~$ echo $HISTFILE
/home/wspace/.bash_history
wspace@mmweb:~$
```

As you can see above, different users have different history file path.

.bash_history file is updated by bash process.